# allocate memory using huge page and numa_tonode_memory giving "Bus Error"

Tags: numa, huge-pages

I am trying to allocate a 2GB buffer using huge TLB page (1GB) and bind the memory region to a specific numa node.

To allocate the buffer using huge TLB page, I am using the following code:

```
shmid = shmget (IPC_PRIVATE, buf_size,
                SHM_HUGETLB | IPC_CREAT | SHM_R | SHM_W);
buf = (uint64_t *) shmat (shmid, 0, 0);
```

Then, I called:

```
numa_tonode_memory (buf, buf_size, 3);
```

to move the buffer to a specific node.

When I run the program, as soon as I access buffer offset larger than 1GB, the program would stop with "Bus error (core dumped)".

Removing numa_tonode_memory would avoid the error, however, it would also destroy the purpose of allocating memory on a specific node.

I am wondering if there is any work around on this problem,

Thank you,

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you reserved Huge Pages? (`grep Huge /proc/meminfo`) Do you have some other process that is reserving huge pages too, and are you sure that you have enough?

Comment: Hi Mark, I actually found a workaround for this problem. It looks like `numa_tonode_memory` can only allocate one huge page on the specified node. I may have used the function incorrectly. The workaround I came up with is to call `numa_run_on_node` before calling `shmget` such that the memory allocated by `shmget` would be reserved on the same node specified in `numa_run_on_node`.